Visualforce with Apex
I feel like a first year spanish student dropped into Spain for a month.  I was able to build the visualforce page, then I tried to add an apex controller to allow selection of specific fields, then hide that selection after choices are made.  I'm including screen shots so you can see what I did and hopefully what I'm trying to do.
 
Apex Code:
AccountController {
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public Boolean includeX401kDateSold { get; set; }
    public Boolean includeActualNoOfEmployees { get; set; }
    public Boolean selectionsSaved { get; set; } // New variable to track save status

    // Constructor
    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.account = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        includeX401kDateSold = false; // Default value
        includeActualNoOfEmployees = false; // Default value
        selectionsSaved = false; // Initial value is false
    }

    // Method to handle saving selections
    public void saveSelections() {
        // Set selectionsSaved to true after saving
        selectionsSaved = true;
        System.debug('saveSelections method called');
        System.debug('includeX401kDateSold: ' + includeX401kDateSold);
        System.debug('includeActualNoOfEmployees: ' + includeActualNoOfEmployees);
    }
}


Visualforce Code
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController"> 
    <script>
        // JavaScript function to hide the selection section
        function hideSelectionSection() {
            var selectionSection = document.getElementById("selectionSection");
            if (selectionSection) {
                selectionSection.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <img src="{!$Resource.sb401klogo}" alt="Company Logo" style="width:200px;height:auto;" />

    <apex:form >
        <!-- Selection Section -->
        <apex:pageBlock title="Select Fields to Display" id="selectionSection">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <!-- Checkboxes for optional fields -->
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!includeX401kDateSold}"/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Include X401k Date Sold"/>

                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!includeActualNoOfEmployees}"/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Include Actual Number of Employees"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <!-- Separate button for hiding selection section -->
                <button type="button" onclick="hideSelectionSection()">Hide Selection</button>
                <!-- Save Selections button for server action -->
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Selections" action="{!saveSelections}" rerender="planDetails"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Plan Details" id="planDetails">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:20%; text-align:left; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                        <th style="width:30%; text-align:left; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;"><strong>Details</strong></th>
                        <th style="width:20%; text-align:left; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;"><strong>Description</strong></th>
                        <th style="width:30%; text-align:left; padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;"><strong>Details</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Type of 401k</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.X401_k_Plan_Type__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Disc Match and/or PS (and type)</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Disc_Match_and_or_PS_and_type__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Vesting Schedule</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Vesting_Schedule__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Eligibility Requirement</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Eligibility_Requirement__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Deferral Percentage Change Frequency</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Deferral_Percentage_Change_Frequency__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Auto Enrollment</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.X401k_Auto_Enrollment__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">QDIA (Qualified Default Investment alt)</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.QDIA__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Roth</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Roth__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Loans / Sources and Restrictions</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Loans__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">In-Service Distributions @ 59 1/2</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.In_Service_Distribution__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Hardship Withdrawals</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Withdrawals__c}</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Pricing</td>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Pricing__c}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Assets Under Management</td>
                         <apex:outputText value="{0, number,currency}">
                                <apex:param value="{!Account.Assets_Under_Management__c}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>
                            <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Optional Fields Rendering -->
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!includeX401kDateSold}">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">X401k Date Sold</td>
                            <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.X401k_Date_Sold__c}</td>
                            <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">Actual Number of Employees</td>
                            <td style="padding:8px; border:1px solid #ddd;">{!Account.Actual_No_of_Employees__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>



Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. Your example is somewhat Minimal, not Complete and therefore not Reproducible.

@grace can you clarify the issue you are experiencing? The question is not very explicit in your post

There standard way of adding optional fields selected by configuration on a VisualForce page is to use field sets -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm
You might try doing something with that.

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
